# Program isn't terminating for a specific input

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will let me know if a number has the odd divisor greater than one. Let's n be the number, and x be the divisor. x%2!=0 and x>1;
Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Simple1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        long n;
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++) {
            n=sc.nextLong();
            if(n<3)System.out.println("NO");
            else {
                
                if(n%2!=0)System.out.println("YES");
                else {
                    int ans=0;
                    for(long j=3; j<=n/2; j+=2) {
                        if(n%j==0) {
                            ans=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(ans==1)System.out.println("YES");
                    else System.out.println("NO");
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This java code works fine. But it's not working for a specific input.. and that is n = 1099511627776. If I change the last digit to any int other than 6, then it works fine and gives output. Even numbers greater than that works. But only this number n=1099511627776, when I input this to my program, no terminating happens and no output. Help me to figure out what happens here.

Comment: The number `1099511627776` is two to the power 40. That means it has to check through the whole big for-loop to find no odd factors. You have to wait longer if you want to do it this way.

Comment: You can add some output in your loop to see what it is checking. You'll see that it is just taking a very long time because you are asking it to check a whole lot of modulo operations.

Comment: To make it (much) faster, you could divide `n` by 2 until you get an odd number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `1099511627776` is two to the power 40. That means it has to check through the whole big for-loop to find no odd factors. You would get the same problem, to different extents, with `2199023255552` (2 to the 41) and `549755813888` (2 to the 39). You have to wait longer if you want to do it this way.

A much faster way is to divide `n` by 2 until you get an odd number.

E.g.

```
long n = sc.nextLong();
while (n > 1 && n % 2 == 0) {
   n /= 2;
}
if (n > 1) {
    System.out.println("Yes.");
} else {
    System.out.println("No.");
}
```

An even faster way to tell if a number is a power of two is a bit-twiddling hack:

```
// Powers of 2 have the property that n & (n-1) is zero
if ((n & (n - 1)) != 0) {
    System.out.println("Yes."); // Not a power of two, so has an odd factor
} else {
    System.out.println("No."); // Is a power of two, so does not have an odd factor
}
```

Comment: If `n` is power of 2 it is a 1 followed by N 0's and `n-1` is N 1's. So when you & them N 0's line up with N 1's and the original 1 is beyond any other 1's. If it isn't a power of two, the leading 1b will remain even after subtracting 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get rid of the powers of two another way?

```
long number = 1099511627776l;
long r = number >> Long.numberOfTrailingZeros​(number);
```

Then r is an odd divisor, which might be greater than one.

If you think in base 10, then you know a number is divisible by ten if has a trailing zero. You can remove all of the powers of 10 by removing all of the zeros. It is the same for base 2, you can remove all of the factors of 2 by removing all of the trailing zeros (in binary representation).

Comment: Yeah it's a great way. Bitwise operation.